# Why In below code month=1 when offsetting easter to find Good friday

Tags: python

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, Holiday,nearest_workday,USMartinLutherKingJr,USColumbusDay,USPresidentsDay,USMemorialDay,USLaborDay,USThanksgivingDay
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay, Day, Easter


class USTradingCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        Holiday('NewYearsDay', month=1, day=1, observance=nearest_workday),
        USMartinLutherKingJr,
        USPresidentsDay,
        USMemorialDay,
        Holiday('USIndependenceDay', month=7, day=4, observance=nearest_workday),
        EasterMonday = Holiday("Easter Monday", month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(1)]),
        USLaborDay,
        USColumbusDay,
        Holiday("Veterans Day", month=11, day=11, observance=nearest_workday),
        USThanksgivingDay,
        Holiday('Christmas', month=12, day=25, observance=nearest_workday)
    ]
```

Comment: I want to know why month=1 is taken in above code

Comment: You need to elaborate your question more. Do you have question about syntax? or is it a logical question that you want to know why month=1 and not e.g. 2 or s.th. else? Furthermore, what are the arguments for this Holiday class?

Comment: Mehndi1902 Yes its about syntax. Since easter mostly falls in April or march . I was wondering why month is taken as one

Comment: You still haven't said what `Holiday` *is*.

Comment: Maybe month and day are 1 because you are using Easter() as an offset from January 1st, but it's just a guess since you don't provide any information about the module...

Comment: John Coleman: from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, Holiday

Comment: Why not edit that into your question?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what's happening is it's starting from January 1st, adding an offset returned by `Easter()` (since the date changes every year, it can't be a hardcoded date like the others), and then since Easter Monday is the day after easter, another `Day()` is added.

Basically what you're getting is `January 1st + Days Until Easter + 1 Day`